# How to see exactly how much memory each add-in is using?

Tags: outlook, windbg

Is there a way for me to see exactly how much memory each Outlook add-in is using? I have a few customers on 32-bit Office who are all having issues with screen flashing and crashing and I suspect that we as a company have deployed too many add-ins, and even with Large Address Awareness (LAA), they're running out of memory which is causing Outlook to freak out.

I didn't see a way to do this in Outlook so i created a .dmp file and I've opened it via windbg, but I'm new to this application and have no clue how to see specific memory usage by specific add-ins (the .dmp file is only of outlook.exe)

Answer (score 1):

The following assumes plugins created in C++ or other "native" languages, at least not .NET.

The allocation of memory with a `new` statement goes to [`HeapAlloc()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366597(v=vs.85).aspx). In order to find out who allocated the memory, that information would need to be stored in the heap as well.

However, you cannot provide that information in the `new` statement, and even if it were possible, you would need to rewrite all the `new` statements in your code.

Another way would be that `HeapAlloc()` has a look at the call stack at the time someone wants memory. In normal operation, that's too much cost (time-wise) and too much overhead (memory-wise). However, it is possible to enable the so called *User Mode Stack Trace Database*, sometimes abbreviated as UST database. You can do that with the tool `GFlags`, which ships with WinDbg.

The tool to capture memory snapshots is `UMDH`, also available with WinDbg. It will store the results as plain text files. It should be possible to extract statistical data from those USTs, however, I'm not aware of a tool that would do that, which means you would need to write one yourself.

The third approach is using the concept of "heap tagging". However, it's quite complex and also needs modifications in your code. I never implemented it, but you can look at the question [How to benefit from Heap tagging by DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264272/how-to-benefit-from-heap-tagging-by-dll)

Let's say the UST approch looks most feasible. How large should the UST database be?

Until now, 50 MB was sufficient for me to identify and fix memory leaks. However, for that use case it's not important to get information about all memory. It just needs enough samples to support a hypothesis. Those 50 MB are IMHO allocated in your application's memory, so it may affect the application.

The UST database only stores the addresses, not the call stack text. So in a 32 bit application, each frame on the call stack only needs 32 bit of storage.

In your case, 50 MB will not be sufficient. Considering an average depth of 10 frames and an average allocation size of 256 bytes (4 bytes for an int, but also larger things like strings), you get

4 GB / 256 bytes = 16M allocations

16M allocations * 10 frames * 4 byte/frame = 640 MB UST

If the given assumptions are realistic (I can't guarantee that), you would need a 640 MB UST database size. This will influence your application much, since it reduces the memory from 4 GB to 3.3 GB, thus the OOM comes earlier.

The UST information should also be available in the DMP file, if it was configured at the time the crash dump was created. Certainly not in your DMP file, otherwise you would have told us. However, it's not available in a way that's good for statistics. Using the UMDH text files IMHO is a better approach.

> Is there a way for me to see exactly how much memory each Outlook add-in is using?

Not with the DMP file you have at the moment. It will still be hard with the tools available with WinDbg.

There are a few other options left:

- Disable all plugins and measure memory of Outlook itself. Then, enable one plugin at a time and measure the memory with that plugin enables. Calculate the difference to find out what additional memory that plugin needs.
- Does it crash immediately at startup? Or later, say after 10 minutes of usage? Could it be a memory leak? Identifying a memory leak could be easier: just enable one plugin at a time and monitor memory usage over time. Use a memory profiler, not WinDbg. It will be much easier to use and it can draw the appropriate graphics you need.

Note that you need to define a clear process to measure memory. Some memory will only be allocated when you do something specific ("lazy initialization"). Perhaps you want to measure that memory, too.

Answer (score 1):

The following assumes plugins created in .NET.

The allocation of memory with a `new` statement goes to the .NET memory manager. In order to find out which plugin allocated the memory, that information would need to be stored in the .NET heap as well.

A UST (*User Mode Stack Trace*) database like available for the Windows Heap Manager is not available in .NET. Also, the .NET memory manager works directly above [`VirtualAlloc()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887(v=vs.85).aspx), so it does not use the Windows Heap Manager. Basically, the reason is garbage collection.

> Is there a way for me to see exactly how much memory each Outlook add-in is using?

No, since this information is not stored in crash dumps and there's no setting to enable it.

What you need is a memory profiler which is specific for .NET.

If you work with .NET and Visual Studio already, perhaps you're using JetBrains Resharper. The Ultimate Edition comes with a tool called [dotMemory](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/), so you might already have a license and you just need to install it via the control panel ("modify" Resharper installation).

It has (and other tools probably have as well) a feature to group memory allocations by assembly:

[image: Screenshot of dotMemory]

The screenshot shows memory allocated by an application called "MemoryPerformance". It retains 202 MB in objects, and those objects are mostly objects of the .NET framework (mscorlib).